# Bing translator widget without original text popup

Tags: php, localization, language-translation, microsoft-translator

I have implemented Bing Translator Widget in my website. It works great. However I could not find any way to disable annoying popups attached to hover event on translated texts that shows original text.

Is there any way I can disable it. Thanks in advance.

Following are links to Official pages about how to use the widget:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn341983.aspx

http://www.bing.com/widget/translator/

http://www.microsoft.com/web/solutions/mstranslator.aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Got the same problem here, and after some explorations, you can do this in javascript :

```
Microsoft.Translator.Widget.domTranslator.showHighlight = false;
Microsoft.Translator.Widget.domTranslator.showTooltips = false;
```

But this must be done after translation, in my case I use [Web Widget Customization API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn341983.aspx), so i can hide tooltips in the **onComplete** callback of [Translate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn341982.aspx) function.

Beware, it's not documented, so I don't know how long this will work. But it's the only way I found.

Answer (score 1):

Use this line of code after loading your javascript.

```
window['_mstConfig'].floaterStylePath = '';
```

This will remove the styling of the popup.