# I need the Bing translator widget without original text popup. Is this possible?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I used the below thing but it didn't work for me Microsoft.Translator.Widget.domTranslator.showHighlight = false;
Microsoft.Translator.Widget.domTranslator.showTooltips = false;

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft no longer supports the translator widget. the available solution is to integrate the Translator Text API in your website or application.

Visit the Microsoft Translator Getting Started page at http://www.aka.ms/TranslatorGettingStarted and follow the steps outlined on the webpage to subscribe to the API.

Let us know if you have additional questions.
Best regards, Gwenda, Microsoft Translator Team

Comment: My issue relates to the   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19093559/bing-translator-widget-without-original-text-popup?s=1|138.7109    and am unable to take out the popover